# SQL Query About second Max salary

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get 2nd highest salary from `Employee` table. So please help me to find out. I tried it by using below query.

```
Select Max(salary) from Employee;
```

It gives the highest salary from salary column. But I want 2nd highest salary.

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: I use database Oracle

Answer (score 2):

```
 select max(sal) from
 (select sal,dense_rank() over (order by sal desc) dr from emp) where dr=2;
```

- If salaries like 5000,3000,3000,2000... Dense_rank() will give you the employees having 3000 salary

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT column1, 
     row_number() over (order by salary desc) as [rownum]
     From sal_table
 ) t
 WHERE [rownum] = 2
```

If there is more than one row with same salary you can use `dense_rank` instead of `row_number()`

Comment: Also dense rank:


    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT column1, 
         dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) as sal_rank
        FROM my_table
     ) t
     WHERE sal_rank = 2;

Comment: @Arnab Thank you for editing. I missed to add from :)

Comment: Don't call your row number rownum, for rownum is a reserved word.

Comment: row_number gives you the highest salary in case more than one employee earns the max(sal). rank gives you no record in that case. Only dense_rank works here.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee
WHERE Salary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee )
```

This gives you second highest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @N int
SET @N = 2  -- Change the value here to pick a different salary rank

SELECT Salary
FROM (
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) as SalaryRank, Salary
    FROM Salaries
) as SalaryCTE
WHERE SalaryRank = @N
```

Comment: Working with row_number you get the highest salary in case more than one employee earns the max(sal).

Answer (score 0):

Not only 2nd Salary but you can get all your desired highest salaries (like 3rd, 5th) by this query.

```
select salary from(select rownum rn,salary from
(select distinct(salary) from emp order by salary desc)) x where x.rn in (1,2,3);
```

Just Replace your desired salary position in place of `(1,2,3)`, like `(3,5)`, so it will give you 3rd and 5th highest salary, like:

```
select salary from(select rownum rn,salary from
(select distinct(salary) from emp order by salary desc)) x where x.rn in (3,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more:

```
 SELECT a.salary
   FROM employee a
  WHERE (:n - 1) = (SELECT COUNT(1)
                     FROM employee b
                    WHERE b.salary > a.salary);
```

Just replace n with the nth highest that you want.